# Want nav menu over background image on splash page but it moves around on various monitors

Tags: css, image, background, position, nav

I'm pretty sure this is an easy fix and I am simply too in experienced to figure it out. I'm building a site, using WP, but the home page is simply a background image with a vertical nav menu. I don't now how to make the menu stay in the same place for all browsers and windows. It looked good on my screen, then I found the nav pane was in a completely different place on my husband's monitor. I believe it has to do with position and display and  margins, but I am getting more lost as I read up on these and I just want someone to tell me the code.

The page is at [www.sydneyjanebaily.com](http://www.sydneyjanebaily.com)

So far the code for the whole page is as follows:

> body {
>   background-image:url(http://www.sydneyjanebaily.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/open-book.png);
>   background-repeat:no-repeat; background-attachment:fixed;
>   background-position:center;
>
> }
>        menu   {     display: block; }
>
> ## access div {     display: block;     margin-left:890px;  margin-right:auto;  margin-top:200px;   width: 235px;       }
>
> /*************************** Navigation **********************/
>   nav#access ul, nav#access li.pagenav {    display: block;     list-style:
>   none; }
>
> nav#access ul li a span, nav#access ul li.page_item a span { position:
>   absolute; right: 100%; top: 2px; width: 15px; height: 100%;
>   background-image: url(../images/nav-shadow.png); background-position:
>   right top; background-repeat: repeat-y; }
>
> nav#access ul li a, nav#access ul li a:visited, nav#access ul
>   li.page_item a, nav#access ul li.page_item a:visited {    display:
>   block;    padding: 8px 10px 8px 30px;     color: white;   font: 150%
>   "EBGaramondSC", "Palatino", "Palatino Linotype","Book Antiqua",
>   Georgia, serif;   text-decoration: none;      /*background-color:
>
> ## aba000; */   margin: 5px 0 7px 0;    position: relative;     width: 235px;       /*font-variant: small-caps;*/  }
>
> nav#access ul li a:hover, nav#access ul li a:focus, nav#access ul
>   li.page_item a:hover, nav#access ul li.page_item a:focus{ color:
>
> ## FF0000; }
>
> nav#access li a:hover span { background-color: #666; } nav#access ul
>   li a em { font-size: 87.50%; } nav#access ul li:nth-child(5n-4) a,
>   nav#access ul li:nth-child(5n-4) a span { ; } nav#access ul
>   li:nth-child(5n-3) a, nav#access ul li:nth-child(5n-3) a span { ; }
>   nav#access ul li:nth-child(5n-2) a, nav#access ul li:nth-child(5n-2) a
>   span { ; } nav#access ul li:nth-child(5n-1) a, nav#access ul
>   li:nth-child(5n-1) a span { ; } nav#access ul li:nth-child(5n-5) a,
>   nav#access ul li:nth-child(5n-5) a span {; } -->
>
> nav#access ul li ul li span { position: absolute; right: 100%; top: 0;
>   width: 20px; height: 100%; left: 2px; margin-right: 15px;  overflow:
>   visible; } nav#access ul li ul li:nth-child(odd) a  { background:
>   none; color: #EEE8AA; font-size: smaller;  margin: 3px 20px 5px 20px; 
>   min-height: 20px; width: 210px; padding: 2px 0 2px 20px; } nav#access
>   ul li ul li:nth-child(odd) a:hover, nav#access ul li ul
>   li:nth-child(odd) a:focus  { background: none; color: #ADFF2F;
>   font-size: smaller; left: 15px; padding: 2px 30px 2px 25px;  }
>   nav#access ul li ul li:nth-child(odd) a span  { background:
>   url(../images/sub-menu2.png) -5px 0px no-repeat; width: 30px; }
>
> nav#access ul li ul li:nth-child(even) a  { background: none; color:
>
> ## 3B3C1D; font-size: smaller;  margin: 3px 20px 5px 20px; min-height: 20px; width: 210px; padding: 2px 0 2px 20px; } nav#access ul li ul
>
> li:nth-child(even) a:hover, nav#access ul li ul li:nth-child(even)
>   a:focus  { background: none; color: #FF4500; font-size: smaller; left:
>   15px; padding: 2px 30px 2px 25px; } nav#access ul li ul
>   li:nth-child(even) a span  { background: url(../images/sub-menu2.png)
>   -5px 0px no-repeat;  width: 30px; }
>
> nav#access ul li ul li ul li:nth-child(odd) a  { background: none;
>   color: #FFD700; font-size: smaller;  margin: 3px 20px 5px 30px; 
>   min-height: 20px; width: 200px; padding: 2px 0 2px 20px; } nav#access
>   ul li ul li ul li:nth-child(odd) a:hover, nav#access ul li ul li ul
>   li:nth-child(odd) a:focus  { background: none; color: #EEE8AA;
>   font-size: smaller; left: 25px; padding: 2px 30px 2px 25px;  }
>   nav#access ul li ul li ul li:nth-child(odd) a span  { background:
>   url(../images/sub-menu.png) -10px 0px no-repeat;  width: 30px;  }
>
> nav#access ul li ul li ul li:nth-child(even) a  { background: none;
>   color: #3B3C1D; font-size: smaller;  margin: 3px 20px 5px 30px;
>   min-height: 20px; width: 200px; padding: 2px 0 2px 20px; } nav#access
>   ul li ul li ul li:nth-child(even) a:hover, nav#access ul li ul li ul
>   li:nth-child(even) a:focus  { background: none; color: #7FFFD4;
>   font-size: smaller; left: 25px; padding: 2px 30px 2px 25px; }
>   nav#access ul li ul li ul li:nth-child(even) a span  { background:
>   url(../images/sub-menu.png) -10px 0px no-repeat;  width: 30px;   }
>
> nav#access ul li a:hover:active, nav#access ul li ul li
>   a:hover:active, nav#access ul li ul li ul li a:hover:active,
>   nav#access ul li a:focus:active, nav#access ul li ul li
>   a:focus:active, nav#access ul li ul li ul li a:focus:active { color:
>
> ## 00CCFF; left: 1px; top: 1px;}
>
> /* Singular navigation */
>
> ## nav-single {     float: right;   position: relative;     top: -0.3em;    text-align: right;  z-index: 1; }
>
> ## nav-single .nav-previous,
>
> ## nav-single .nav-next {   float: none;    width: auto; }
>
> ## nav-single .nav-next {   padding-left: .5em; }
>
> ```
>     img.book {  
>         /* Set rules to fill background */  
>         min-height: 100%;  
>         min-width: 1000px;  
>
>         /* Set up proportionate scaling */  
>
>         height: auto;  
>
>         /* Set up positioning */  
>
>         top: 0;  
>         left: 0;  
>
>       display: block;   
>       margin-left: auto;  
>       margin-right: auto; 
>       text-align: center;
>     } 
>
>     </style>  
>
>   <!-- <img class="book"src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/open-book.png" alt="xxx"
> ```
>
> width="880" height="xxx" />  -->
>
> ```
>           <?php /*  Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
>           <!-- <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content',
> ```
>
> 'twentyeleven' ); ?>">
>                 "> -->
>                 
>                  'primary' ) ); ?>

I am puzzled that when I inspect an element using Firefox developer tool, it still says inline element for things I've marked as block.

Basically, I can put the nav pane where I want using px but it only looks right on my screen. I think I need percentages, but that is beyond me. Please help.

Thanks,
Sydney

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing this:

```
#access div {
    display: block;
    margin-left:890px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:200px;
    width: 235px;  
    }
```

with this:

```
#access div {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20%;
   left: 50%;
}
```

It works well on my monitor no matter how I squash or stretch the screen, and it should work for you as well.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for that. Really! What a relief. One more question if you don't mind. It worked well on Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but on IE (at least whatever old version is on my husband's pc though never used), the nav was unstyled, just words with bullets in the upper left of screen as if none of the css impacted it. Any suggestions for IE users?

Comment: Also, if I don't want to screw it all up again, is there a way to make it all smaller easily?  What I mean is that I have a big screen, like 24 inches, but all the other monitors in my home are smaller, 17 and smaller, and I see that this book image looks really smooshed and the bookmark is a little cut off top and bottom. So I'm thinking just a wee bit smaller would work for most people. Is there a way to make it adjust or should I just tell it to make the image smaller?Thanks very very much. Sydney

Comment: If your husband is using IE 6 or older, there aren't any guarantees for CSS working in it unfortunately.  However, in regards to your question about the background image, the most straight forward method to fix this would be resizing the image.  Otherwise you can make it into its own div and resize it dynamically, but that might be more work than it is worth to you.

Comment: I checked and it's IE8 but we never use it. Still I imagine many people do. So I guess I need to figure out how to make my simple nav show up in IE. As to the other question, did my book look too big to you on your screen? Thanks again.

Comment: Nope, the book looked fine on my monitor (1440x900).

The unstyled menu also happens in IE 9 (I just checked).  The stylesheet is very complex, and I see a lot of -webkit styles, which will not work in IE at all.  Keep an eye out for those(and replace them with more generic styles), clean up your styles a bit (it can be done, if you put in a little time) and keep up the good work :)